# How to become a member of the "Totally Insane Travel Society"?

Tags: events, group-travel, eclipses

The Totally Insane Travel Society organizes travels to see solar eclipses. As you can see in [this video](https://tv.nrk.no/serie/distriktsnyheter-nordnytt/DKTR99031915/19-03-2015#t=6m33s) some of their members were in Svalbard to see the eclipse of the 20th of March this year. But I can't find any information about this travel society.

Comment: Solar eclipse is insane? Even traveling to Disney land is more insane...

Comment: You can go to the next solar eclipse and look for their membership booth. Seriously, a loosely formed collection of enthusiasts describing themselves with a name would not mean that it's a formal 'society'.

Comment: T.I.T.S.  Really

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about local societies.

Comment: There are a ton of groups that go to eclipses (i've been to three - self organised). The one in Cairns in 2013 had 75k Aussies and 75k foreigners in town (estimated)! As for T.I.T.S., I suspect that's just a name for a small group of friends/tourists, the only search results for them show this question and a similar [offhand mention](https://britastro.org/node/6347).

Comment: What is your question?